# MGTwitterEngine Not Working on iPad

Tags: objective-c, mgtwitterengine

Hello how to use MGTwitterEngine on iPad...

i have add this code on viewDidLoad but presentModelViewController is not call i have debug the code... please let me know what i do wrong:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(_engine) return;

    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey = consumerKeyString;
    _engine.consumerSecret = consumerSecretKeyString;

    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

    if (controller) 
        [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    else {
        tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self updateStream:nil];
    }

}
```

the presentModelView is call but twitter login view is not intiated .. please tell me thanks

I am using iOS 3.2

Comment: Have you done anything to tell if viewDidLoad is being called, or what path is taken through viewDidLoad?  Use the debugger, or add some NSLogs to determine those things, and take it from there.